# I have this id in XML file android:id="@+id/search_edit_text" how to import to the kotlin file?

Tags: kotlin

I have this id in XML  <EditText  *android:id="@+id/search_edit_text*" , how to import to the kotlin file. In kotlin file need use this view.search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener for my program , but appear this error "Unresolved reference: search_edit_text"

a little of my program source :

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_search)
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        mUser = ArrayList()
        userAdapter = context?.let { UserAdapter(it, mUser as ArrayList<User>, true) }
        recyclerView?.adapter = userAdapter

        view.search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher
```

my XML file:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/search_fragment_icon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_fragment_icon"
                    android:hint="Pesquisar..."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout_search"
        android:visibility="gone"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please share the XML file as well. Is the textView in the recyclerView Xml File?

Comment: I put now my xml code